# Make UINavigationBar white and without border

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to remove a border from `UINavigationBar` while making it completely white so that it blends with the background.

Here is the code which I have:

```
nav.navigationBar.standardAppearance.shadowColor = UIColor.white //also tried UIColor.clear
nav.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
nav.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
nav.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
nav.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

The end result is depicted in the image below. As you can see, my navigation bar is not completely white:

[image]

If I remove the line where I set `shadowColor` I do get a white background, but with a line at the bottom.

I would appreciate if someone could help me to get the result which I want.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code:

```
let appearance                      = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.backgroundColor          = .white
appearance.shadowColor              = .none
appearance.titleTextAttributes      = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor            = .black
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance   = appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance    = appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

Comment: same result. Updated question

Comment: Updated, check now.